# #vmix ayuda con transmision

Tags: javascript, html5

soy nuevo con vmix y acabo de ingresar a trabajar a un canal de tv local e cual me pide como su desarrollador web que transmita el programa por Internet sin utilizar un tercero como ustream o livestream es decir un reproductor gratuito.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que me puedan dar o decir como puedo lograrlo.

o alguna forma de desarrollar un reproductor que pueda conectarlo a vmix